# Optimize space complexity of Knapsack solution

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem

Below is the typical Knapsack working solution using bottom up approach .How can I optimize the space complexity for it?
Currently space complexity is 0(rows*columns)

```
 int val[] = new int[] { 60, 100, 120 };
            int wt[] = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
            int capacity= 50; //capacity of knapsack
            int n = val.length;
            System.out.println(knapsack(capacity, wt, val, n)); //220

public static int knapsack(int c, int wt[], int val[], int n) {
        
        int dp[][] = new int[n+1][c+1];
        
        for( int i =0 ;i < n+1;i++)
            for( int j =0 ;j < c+1;j++)
              if( i==0 || j==0 )
                  dp[i][j]=0;
        
        
        for( int i =1;i < n+1;i++)
        {
            for( int j =1 ;j < c + 1;j++)
            {
                
                if ( wt[i-1] <= j)
                {
                    dp[i][j] = Math.max(val[i-1]+ dp[i-1][j-wt[i-1]] , dp[i-1][j]);
                } else 
                {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
                }
            }
        
        }
        
        return dp[n][c];

    
    }
```

Comment: note that all dp acess is dp[i-1], meaning you don't need to store more than the previous row.

Comment: You can actually do it with one row, by iterating backwards through the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate it with only 1-D dp array, make dp array of size W, and at the end of the calculation `dp[W]` will store the answer after calculation, Below is the code in c++ :

```
int knapsack(int c, int wt[], int val[], int n){
       
        vector<int> dp(W+1, 0);
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            
            for(int j=W; j>=wt[i]; j--){
                
                dp[j] = max(dp[j], val[i] + dp[j-wt[i]]);
            }
        }
        return dp[W];
}
```